# Where are all the parents in the Harry Potter movies?

Tags: harry-potter

An entire school of children made to battle in a magical war? Where are their parents? Did the students need permission slips to join the battle?

Comment: Kid comes home: "Mom, dad, there is a war going on. I have to help my friends fight this evil villain who is trying to take over our school." Parents: "That's cool son, be sure to call if you are not joining us for dinner."

Comment: Some of the parents are right there in the battles.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLtZmKyeW6g

Comment: yes alot of the parents show up, their just wasnt time to contact everyone, but most of the anti voldemort group new eachother and so had some means of informing eachother of the battle at hogwartts.  also i cant remember 100% for sure but believe the younger children were kept out of most of the fighting, the slytherlins were also mostly out of the fight as well.

Comment: On a more serious note, the parents of the important characters are either there or dead. The rest of the parents are probably just left out to avoid 1000+ new faces near the end of the story.

Comment: @Himarm -- It's untrue the Slytherins were out of the picture. After some initial resistance, the Slytherins -- led by Slughorn -- fought against Voldemort. They did their part! :D

Comment: @Slytherincess Really? I only recall them being sent out of Hogwarts by McGonagall, though possibly that only meant/included the underage Slytherins.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - JKR said she enjoyed writing Slughorn leading the Slytherins back to the battle to fight against Voldemort. And after the battle, Phineas Nigellus calls out 'in his high, reedy voice, ‘And let it be noted that Slytherin house played its part! Let our contribution not be forgotten!’ Ah, for the life of me I can't find JKR's quote right now, but it was sweet and funny. :)

Comment: Which battle are you referring to?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

What isn't portraited in the movies that well is that the world at which the last movies take place is a very tense one. Some parents didn't let their kids go to Hogwarts, because it wasn't considered safe. Or they let them go, if they were going to abide by every rule. There was a lot of fear in the air. Even for the grown-up wizards, they couldn't say anything due to fear of retaliation from Death Eaters (in this case, the goverment itself). So, when the call to fight came, only some showed up. while the most part, just sat still waiting for the storm to pass.

Also a some of the student's parents were dead. Some were not even wizards at all, Hermione was muggle born.

So if you count everything up, you don't get a lot more adults to help out the kids.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back this up at all? Quotes from the books?

Comment: Tense climate: 
When Ron returns to Harry and Hermione and tells them how life is on the outside. 
Griphook's story of his run with a hogwarts student.
Students not going back to hogwarts:
the hunt of muggles borns.
Dead parents:
Harry's and Neville's

Answer (score 5):

The question seems like it's based on some misconceptions, though I haven't seen the later movies so perhaps that is the situation that's presented in them.

> An entire school of children made to battle in a magical war?

It wasn't the entire school, and they weren't "made" to fight. The teachers stayed to fight, and students who were of age (seventeen years old) were allowed to choose whether they fought in the battle or not.

> Where are their parents?

Probably at home asleep - or at least trying to sleep - considering it was the middle of the night. Many of them wouldn't have known anything was happening at Hogwarts until their evacuated children turned up back at home with the news. By that point they'd likely be unable to get to the battle safely due to the Death Eaters, giants, etc. surrounding the grounds, and their primary concern would likely to be to stay with their children to ensure they were protected.

Those that turned up did so before the fighting started, just as the Hogwarts students who weren't old enough to fight were being evacuated. They were also those who had close ties to Harry, Ron and Hermione through being members of either the Order of the Phoenix or Dumbledore's Army, and had more direct means of communication to learn about Voldemort's attack.

> Did the students need permission slips to join the battle?

As I mentioned earlier, it was only students who were of age that were (supposed to be) fighting in the battle. Since they're legally considered adults in Wizarding society it's their choice to make, with or without their parents' agreement or permission.

Comment: A lot came to fight: *And now there were more, even more people storming up the front steps, and Harry saw Charlie Weasley overtaking Horace Slughorn, who was still wearing his emerald pyjamas. They seemed to have returned at the head of what looked like the **families** and friends of every Hogwarts student who had remained to fight, along with the shopkeepers and homeowners of Hogsmeade.* - *Deathly Hallows*

Comment: @Slytherincess I suppose it depends on your definition of "a lot", but I see your point. However, it also says "of every Hogwarts student who had remained to fight", which I think is an important distinction. Coming to Hogwarts when your child is already there seems like it would be an entirely different proposition to leaving your child alone at home to go to Hogwarts and fight.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Is there a way I can contact you off site?

Answer (score -4):

At home, ignorant as to what was going on or on one side of the fight or the other.  The battle of Hogwarts lasted a couple hours at most.  The parents that weren't participating in the fighting continued to send their kids to the school to maintain the illusion that everything was fine.  They were basically condesending to their kids' intelligence.

Comment: "The parents that weren't participating in the fighting continued to send their kids to the school to maintain the illusion that everything was fine." They didn't have a choice, when Voldemort was in charge of the Ministry of Magic it was compulsory for school aged children to attend. They weren't "condesending to their kids' intelligence" or trying to pretend that everything was fine, they were following the law so they weren't dragged from their homes and imprisoned, tortured or murdered.